# If a relation R is symmetric, so is $R^k$ for any $k\gt0$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

How can I prove that when a relation $R$ is symmetric, the $k^{th}$power of the relation $R$ ($R^k$ ($k\gt0$)) is also symmetric?

Comment: By induction on k.

Comment: Start by showing, as a lemma, that if $R_1,R_2$ are symmetric relations on a set $S$, then $R_1 \circ R_2$ is a symmetric relation on $S$. Then apply this lemma to your problem (by induction on k).